# Function's Transformation's Roots.

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $f(x)=x^3+3x^2+6x+2\sin x$
Transformed into:
$$g(x)=\frac{1}{x-f(1)}+\frac{1}{x-f(2)}+\frac{3}{x-f(3)}$$
What can be said about the number of roots of this transformation.
$$f(1)=10+2\sin1,f(2)=32+2\sin2$$
I am not calculating $f(3)$ because I get the Idea this is not gonna work.
OK asymptotes? It would have at $f(1),f(2),f(3)$ but that can't help. 
Please help how many roots it'll have. No,1,2,more than 2, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}g(x)=0$ and that for $i=1,2,3$
$$\lim_{x\to f(i)^{\pm}}=\pm\infty.$$

Also, both for $f(1)\lt x\lt f(2)$ and for $f(2)\lt x\lt f(3)$, $g(x)$ is decreasing.

Hence, the number of roots of $g(x)$ is $2$.

**Added** : For $f(1)\lt x\lt f(2)$, $g(x)$ is decreasing because each of $\frac{1}{x-f(1)},\frac{1}{x-f(2)},\frac{1}{x-f(3)}$ is decreasing. This can be done also for the case for $f(2)\lt x\lt f(3)$.

Comment: By wolfram, you can see [the graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%28x-%2810%2B2sin%281%29%29%29%2B1%2F%28x-%2832%2B2sin%282%29%29%29%2B1%2F%28x-%2872%2B2sin%283%29%29%29%3D0).

Comment: please explain in detail, sorry for my request.

Comment: Of course, I'll do, but for what part?

Comment: second last line, and yes the `\pm` in not syncronous maybe?

Comment: @ADG: I added a bit. And $\pm$ *is* syncronous. See the graph in my first comment. You'll see why.