# Finding the zeros of $ g(x) = \frac{1}{x-a} + \frac{1}{x-b} + \frac{1}{x-c}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> $$ g  = \frac{1}{x-f(1)} +  \frac{3}{x- f(2) }  + \frac{4}{x-f(3)}$$
> And,
> $$ f(x) = x^3 + 6x^2 + 12x + 108$$
> Find number of real solutions to $g=0$

A 'brute force' way to approach this is by simplfying $g$ :

$$  \frac{(x-f(2) ) (x-f(3) ) + 3 (x-f(1) ) ( x- f(3) )  + 4 (x-f(1) ) (x-f(2) )}{(x-f(1) ) (x-f(2) ) (x-f(3) ) }=g(x)$$

After this, we can find the roots by seeing the behaviour of the function:
$$(x-f(2) ) (x-f(3) ) + 3 (x-f(1) ) ( x- f(3) )  + 4 (x-f(1) ) (x-f(2) )=q(x)$$

and evaluating $q$ at $f(1)$ , $f(2)$ and $f(3)$, and using the identity (from evaluating the function) of :

$$ f(1) < f(2) < f(3)$$

This leads to total roots as zero as we find$ q(f(1) ) $ is postive $q(f(2) ) $ is negative and $q(f(3) )$ is positive, and intermediate value theorem gives the answer.

However, I find this method quite lengthy and algebra messy, is there a faster and maybe easier method?

Comment: Similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1232727/functions-transformations-roots

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$g'(x) = -\frac{1}{(x-f(1))^2} - \frac{3}{(x- f(2))^2 }  - \frac{4}{(x-f(3))^2} < 0$$
which means $g(x)$ is always decreasing. However, we should take into account that the graph of $g$ consists of many lines.

Also, note that
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty} g(x) = 0^-, \qquad \lim_{x\to+\infty} g(x) = 0^+$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to a^-}g(x) = -\infty, \qquad \lim_{x\to a^+}g(x) = +\infty \\
\lim_{x\to b^-}g(x) = -\infty, \qquad \lim_{x\to b^+}g(x) = +\infty \\
\lim_{x\to c^-}g(x) = -\infty, \qquad \lim_{x\to c^+}g(x) = +\infty$$
Hence, there are two roots: one in $(a, b)$ and another in $(b, c)$.

---

Using the above analysis, we can easily verify by hand that he graph has the following form:

> > [image]

Comment: "that the graph of g consists of many lines." I don't get this point, could you explain it a bit more?

Comment: @Buraian I intended to say $g(x)$ has discontinuities of second type at $f(1)$, $f(2)$, and $f(3)$. This means the graph has $4$ separated continuous components in $(-\infty, f(1))$, $(f(1),f(2))$, $(f(2), f(3))$, and $(f(3), +\infty)$.

Comment: Right, so the graph must be analyzed seperately for each closed interval? @VIVID

Comment: @Buraian Having stated that the function is decreasing everywhere in each component, we just need to show that $g$ is of different signs at the endpoints of the intervals.

Answer (score 1):

Note that with $3$ terms in $g(x)$ then $q(x)$ will at always be of second degree, so this is easily soluble.

In fact $g(x)=\dfrac 1{x-a}+\dfrac 1{x-b}+\dfrac 1{x-c}=\dfrac {3x^2-2(a+b+c)x+(ab+bc+ca)}{(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)}$

So the roots are $$\frac13{(a+b+c)}\pm\frac 13\sqrt{(a+b+c)^2-3(ab+bc+ca)}$$

Depending on $a,b,c$ you may have $0,1$ or $2$ roots, depending on the sign of the inners of the square root.

Comment: What's under that square root actually is always nonnegative, as it can be rewritten as $\frac{1}{4} (b+c-2a)^2 + \frac{3}{4} (b-c)^2$. So it is also zero only when all three are equal.

Comment: Though I guess there must be some twist when exactly two of them are equal.

Answer (score 0):

We'll consider four intervals $(-\infty, a),(a,b), (b,c),(c,\infty)$. Let's call these $A,B,C,D$ respectively. Here $a\lt b\lt c$.

On each of these intervals: $g'(x)\lt 0$. By Rolle's theorem, $g(x)=0$ can have at most 1 root in each of the intervals considered above.

Now we'll analyze each of the above intervals.

$A$: $g(x)\to -\infty$ as $x\to a^-$. No root here.

$B$: $g(x)\to \infty $ as $x\to a^+$ and $g(x)\to -\infty$ as $x\to b^-$, which means that given any $M\gt 0, M'\lt 0$, there exist $\delta,\delta'\gt 0$ such that $a\lt x\lt a+\delta\implies g(x)\gt M$ and $b-\delta'\lt x\lt b\implies g(x)\lt M'\lt 0$. Choose $x_1,x_2$ such that $a\lt x_1\lt a+\delta$ and $b-\delta'\lt x_2\lt b$. Hence, by IVT, there is root of $g(x)=0$ on $[x_1,x_2]$.

$C:$ As in $B$, there is a root of $g(x)=0$ in C.

$D$: No root as in $A$.

Comment: Well, within each subinterval where $g$ is continuous anyway...

Comment: Huh but the answer says it should two roots hmm

Comment: @Ian: Thanks . Thanks Buraian

Comment: @Buraian: Please refer this revised answer.

Comment: @Ian: Please refer revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind, all you want to know here is *how many* times the curve $y=g(x)$ crosses the $x$ axis, not *where*. So a certain amount of qualitative thinking will get the answer.

To begin, it's easy to see that rationalizing the expression for $g(x)$ produces a *quadratic* over a cubic, so there can be at *most* two roots. Next, note that the expression for $f(x)$ guarantees that $f(1)\lt f(2)\lt f(3)$, so in particular they are not equal. Finally, note that $g(x)\to+\infty$ as $x\to f(k)^+$ for $k=1$ and $2$ while $g(x)\to-\infty$ as $x\to f(k)^-$ for $k=2$ and $3$. Since $g(x)$ is continuous elsewhere, the Intermediate Value Theorem tells us it must cross the $x$ axis somewhere between $f(1)$ and $f(2)$, and again between $f(2)$ and $f(3)$. Thus there are *exactly* two zeroes.